# How to split the values of array into key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript code and I need to separate the values into separate key-value set.

```
masterName = [
  {ID : 1, Name : "Nigel"},
  {ID : 2, Name : "Jack"},
  {ID : 3, Name : "John"},
  {ID : 4, Name : "Mark"},
  {ID : 5, Name : "Luke"},
  {ID : 6, Name : "Peter"},
  {ID : 7, Name : "James"},
  {ID : 8, Name : "Ravi"}
];

console.log(Object.keys(masterName));

console.log(Object.values(masterName));
```

Comment: Using `map`?  `console.log(masterName.map(({ID}) => ID));`

Comment: this too worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can make use of the `Array.prototype.forEach()`

Example:

```js
let obj = {};

masterName.forEach(value => {
 obj[value.ID] = value.Name;
});

console.log(obj);
// For getting the keys:
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
// For getting the values:
console.log(Object.values(obj));
```